# Compare Doubles to do specific actions depending of results in Swift

Tags: swift, double

I have a input that I transformed in to a `Double`, that I need to compare with 3 different `intervals`, and depending on the `interval`, it should do a specific action.
example:

```
if myDouble < 10 then myDouble * 100   
if myDouble between 10 and 20 then (myDouble * 50) + 1000
if myDouble > 20 then (myDouble * 20) + 1500
```

Comment: Take a look at [The Swift Programming Language: Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html); it's got all the information you need.

Comment: I agree with ABakerSmith, you should read how the language works first, Apple made a very easy to follow introduction

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you declared `myDouble` as a `var` and not `let`:

```
if myDouble < 10 {
    myDouble *= 100
} else if myDouble > 20 {
    myDouble *= 20
} else {
    myDouble *= 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code would look something like this (if you want to assign always to `myDouble`):

```
if myDouble < 10 {
    myDouble = myDouble * 100
} else if myDouble <= 20 {
    myDouble = (myDouble * 50) + 1000
} else if myDouble > 20 {
    myDouble = (myDouble * 20) + 1500
}
```